# Both-sided transparency in ArcScene for extruded features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, transparency-opacity, extrude

I'd like to extrude my polylines and make them transparent, but from both sides. As you can see below, the transparency works only on one side. I think it's something with the side-orientation.

I can create two halves of circle with inverse orientation and extrude them separately, but it won't work after a change of view.

[image]

Comment: +1 For the extremely nice graphic and an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where I think you will need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com) to request that the level of transparency that you seek be supported.

If you are planning to use ArcGIS Pro soon then it will be worth looking there to see whether this is already supported there.